# AngularJs - Filter an object only by certain fields in a custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, filtering, angular-ui, angularjs-filter

I'm working on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVQjpJ). The data comes from an array of objects, and I need to make a filter only by **name** and **amount**.

I have this code, but if you type a character in the search box, it only search by **amount**, and not by **name** too. In other words, if the you type '**warren**' or '**37.47**' it has to return the same result, but doesn't works.

```
var filterFilter = $filter('filter');
 $scope.filter = {
 condition: ""
};
$scope.$watch('filter.condition',function(condition){
 $scope.filteredlist = filterFilter($scope.expenses,{name:condition} && {amount:condition});
 $scope.setPage();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally (based in the [idea](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpQZBN) of [Abhilash P A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1979465/abhilash-p-a) and reading the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)), I solved my question in this way:

```
var filterFilter = $filter('filter');
   $scope.filter = {
     condition: ""
   };
   $scope.$watch('filter.condition',function(condition){
     $scope.filteredlist = filterFilter($scope.expenses,function(value, index, array){
        if (value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(condition.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ) {
          return array;
        }
        else if (value.amount.indexOf(condition) >= 0 ) {
          return array;
        }
     });
     $scope.setPage();
   });
```

The final [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwYgjE) ! (awsome)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a custom filter for your app.

```
directiveApp.filter("myFilter", function () {
    return function (input, searchText) {
        var filteredList = [];

        angular.forEach(input, function (val) {
            // Match exact name
            if (val.name == searchText) {
                filteredList.push(val);
            }
            // Match exact amount
            else if (val.amount == searchText) {
                filteredList.push(val);
            }
        });
        input = filteredList;
        return input;
    };
});
```

You can write your logic in this filter and now use this filter to filter your list.

**Update**

You can just implement this filter to your custom filter `pagination`.

Here is the new version of your code. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpQZBN?editors=101)

**List of updates on your code**

1. Added new filter parameter to your ng-repeat attribute

   ng-repeat="expense in filteredlist | pagination: pagination.currentPage : numPerPage : filter.condition"

   ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I updated my question with more specific explanation.

Comment: @robe007 sorry for the late reply. Please have a look at my answer. I didn't complete my answer. Sorry, I am in an urgent work.